# How to write output to powershell GUI with Scripts

Tags: powershell, user-interface, scripting, automation

Powershell novice here.  I'm trying to write a useful tool that has 3 buttons and a text window.  Each button calls a different powershell (*.ps1) script that do various things. If I can I would like to write the output of those scripts to the GUI text window, but that seems to be harder to do than one would think.  If that's too much then at the minimum I would like to atleast display that the script has ran to completion in the text window.  Something like "* script has been ran".

Here is what I have so far.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function call_Clean 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1"     
}

function call_CreateTestLabConfig 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script2.ps1"   

}

function call_LocalDeploy 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script3.ps1"     
}

function CreateFormButton ( $locationheight, $locationwidth, $sizeheight, $sizewidth, $fieldname, $functionname ) {
  $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
  $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($locationheight, $locationwidth) 
  $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizeheight, $sizewidth) 
  $Button.Text = $fieldname 
  $Button.Add_Click( $functionname ) 
  $Form.Controls.Add($Button) 
}

function CreateStartPosition ( $FormSize, $FormLocation ) {
 $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size ($varFrmMSizeWidth, $varFrmMSizeHeight)
 $Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($varFrmMLocationX, $varFrmMLocationY)
  $Form.Controls.Add($TextWindow) 
}


function CreateTextWindow ( $locationHeight, $LocationWidth, $TextBoxHeight, $TextBoxWidth ) {
  $TextWindow = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
  $TextWindow.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($textBoxHeight,$textBoxWidth)
  $TextWindow.location = new-object system.drawing.point($locationHeight,$LocationWidth)
  $Form.Controls.Add($TextWindow) 
}


$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Test Lab Tool"
#$Form.TopMost = $true
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (475, 600)
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4000, 300)


CreateFormButton 20 100 120 40 'Clean' ${function:call_Clean}
CreateFormButton 170 100 120 40 'Create TestLab Config' ${function:call_CreateTestLabConfig}
CreateFormButton 315 100 120 40 'Local Deploy'
CreateTextWindow 20 160 415 375 'Test'

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Replace your functions to do `& "Script.ps1"`.  All dot-sourcing does is dump the contents of the script into those function blocks.

Comment: Will this help with outputting to the text window?

Comment: It'll help your script run at all.  The output from those scripts will go to the output stream unless you redirect or capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is very linear. When you call a script it's going to freeze the GUI up until it is completed. You can update the GUI with information based on the return from your script, or, simply wait until the script has completed and update the GUI with the information that the script is complete.

For example:

```
function call_Clean 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1"
      $TextWindow.Text = "Call Clean Script Completed"
}
```

Or:

You can use the same GUI update, `$TextWindow.Text = "Call Clean Script Completed"` in the Click Event of your button after your script has completed.

I've updated your code a little bit to show how to access the text attribute of the textwindow. ===========================================================================

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function call_Clean 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1"
        $Form.Controls | % {
            if($_ -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] -and $_.Name -eq "TestTextBox")
            {
                $_.Text = "test"
            }
        }
}

function call_CreateTestLabConfig 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script2.ps1"   

}

function call_LocalDeploy 
{
      # Here the path to call your script
      . "C:\Scripts\Script3.ps1"     
}

function CreateFormButton ( $locationheight, $locationwidth, $sizeheight, $sizewidth, $fieldname, $functionname ) {
  $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
  $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($locationheight, $locationwidth) 
  $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizeheight, $sizewidth) 
  $Button.Text = $fieldname 
  $Button.Add_Click( $functionname ) 
  $Form.Controls.Add($Button) 
}

function CreateStartPosition ( $FormSize, $FormLocation ) {
 $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size ($varFrmMSizeWidth, $varFrmMSizeHeight)
 $Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($varFrmMLocationX, $varFrmMLocationY)
 $Form.Controls.Add($TextWindow) 
}


function CreateTextWindow ( $locationHeight, $LocationWidth, $TextBoxHeight, $TextBoxWidth, $name) {
  $TextWindow = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
  $TextWindow.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($textBoxHeight,$textBoxWidth)
  $TextWindow.location = new-object system.drawing.point($locationHeight,$LocationWidth)
  $TextWindow.Name = $name
  $TextWindow.Multiline = $true
  $Form.Controls.Add($TextWindow) 
}


$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Test Lab Tool"
#$Form.TopMost = $true
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (475, 600)
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4000, 300)


CreateFormButton 20 100 120 40 'Clean' ${function:call_Clean}
CreateFormButton 170 100 120 40 'Create TestLab Config' ${function:call_CreateTestLabConfig}
CreateFormButton 315 100 120 40 'Local Deploy'
CreateTextWindow 20 160 415 375 'TestTextBox'

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hmm the script is executing but i'm still not recieving any output to the text window.  Also when I use the $TextWindow.Text it's not showing that .Text is a property that hangs off of $TextWindow

Comment: I noticed you're using a ListView for your TextWindow. Is that intentional? Or were you wanting to use something like a TextBox?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I actually just realized that as well and i was able to write to the text box if i did it inside the function CreateTextWindow.  It wont write to the text box if i try to use the $textWindow.Text inside the function call_clean.  It gives this error ...

Comment: The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: Add a Name attribute to your constructors. Since you're building your GUI buttons and textbox on the fly you still need to be able to reference their names at some point. Alternatively you can create each button separately, and then directly reference the variable name, (e.g., $textwindow, $button1, $button2, etc.)

Comment: This helped a ton! thank you i've got it displaying to the text box as well as some exception messages I wanted there as well.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked for you. Don't forget to mark this question as answered if it works out for you. :)

Comment: If I could steal your brain for some further information.  I've got the messages writing to the text box.  Is there a way to get the console output from the scripts that are executing to the text box?

Comment: You would have to save the output into an object, array, etc., in the script and then use `return` to return it back at the end of the script run. That would be returned to a variable that you can send to your text box.

Comment: Do you have a minor example using return?

Comment: It's hard to say depending on how you have your scripts structured. To return from a full script the return would be the last thing done so `return $myvalues` in the script and in the GUI `. "C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1"` where you're calling your script you would set that to a value `$myReturnValue = . "C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1"` and then pipe that value to your TextWindow

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest assigning the output of those scripts to a variable and parsing through that information (or just implementing logic if you know the output) to send to the GUI.  For example, if you use Write-Output, it'll be captured when assigned to a variable e.g.

```
$Out = & "Script.ps1"
```

Then you can do something like

```
ForEach ($o in $Out)
{
    $str[] += $o
    $TextWindow.Text = $str
    Update()
}
```

*Note: I don't have WindowsForms experience*